# How to throw a null pointer exception and where

Tags: java, exception

When I have a potential null input... is it better to always check for it:

```
public void doSomething(String str) {

    if (str == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();


    processData(str);
}
```

or pass on the invalid data, and wait for "processData()" to throw the nullPointerException:

```
public void doSomething(String str) {       

    processData(str);
}
```

Comment: it depends - if processData is an internal function (not accessible as a public interface), it might not do a null pointer check. Even if it does, it depends if you have code before processData that needs to run.

Comment: I think, need to check first, if not NULL then pass ahead. so that in future any further modification comes on other module not get affected by null pointer.

Comment: There are also some annotations for non-null parameters. But the trend seems that non-null is in general assumed. In java 8 use `Optional<String>` for possibly missing values. So a javadoc comment would be entirely sufficient.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322638/is-it-okay-to-throw-nullpointerexception-programatically check this link.

Comment: This does not seem to be a duplicate to me.

Comment: @wero For me both discussions ware close enough but I could be wrong. You can vote to reopen if you wish.

Answer (score 6):

This is opinionated, but imho it is better to throw it in the first layer:

If you got a stracktrace and see a NPE (deep down) inside a library implementation it is not clear if it was caused by a bug in the library or by your illegal argument.

For the same reason I would recommend to use a descriptive `IllegalArgumentException` instead of a NPE:

```
if (str == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("str is null");
```

(and give `str` a better name, too).

Comment: I just want to add that above code can be rewritten as `Objects.requireNonNull(str,"str is null");`