# Generic array tail function

Tags: java

Need to make this generic:

```
public static String[] tail(String[] array) {
    String[] result = new String[array.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(array, 1, result, 0, result.length);
    return result;
}
```

Such that:

```
assertArrayEquals(new Integer[]{2, 3}, tail(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));

assertArrayEquals(new String[]{"B", "C"}, tail(new String[]{"A", "B", "C"}));

assertArrayEquals(new String[]{"C"}, tail(tail(new String[]{"A", "B", "C"})));

assertArrayEquals(new String[]{}, tail(new String[]{"A"}).length);
```

And such that `tail(new String[0])` is illegal.

I can't find anything on SO for tail on array, just tail of `List`s etc, but I want to use in the context of variable length argument lists without converting the array to a `List`.

Example usage of tail with variable length argument:

```
public static File file(String root, String... parts) {
    return file(new File(root), parts);
}

public static File file(File root, String... parts) {
    if (parts.length == 0)
        return root;
    return file(new File(root, parts[0]), tail(parts));
}
```

Comment: Downvote is for not clear, not useful, or not researched. Please elaborate to which you think this falls under.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static <T> T[] tail(T[] array) {
    if (array.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array cannot be empty");

    return java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length);
}
```

Note I recommend overloading for primitive types to avoid boxing.

Comment: what if you you pass null?

Comment: @TaharBakir You get a NPE from `array.length`, which I'm OK with.

Comment: if (array==null || array.length == 0) You don't get the npe and you throw that runtimeEx but if it's ok, no arguing here :)

Comment: @TaharBakir I see, yes you could do that, but I would use a different message if I was going to do that because `null` isn't the same as an empty array.

Comment: @TaharBakir Been looking in to this, and if I was to throw a custom exception on `null`, that exception should be `NullPointerException` over any other exception type anyway. So no point throwing it myself. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3323006/360211 and the first comment.